# Question related to a concave function and whether a specific function based on it is concave

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this problem that gave me a concave function f:[0,∞)->[0,∞), and a number p$\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and asked me to show that the function g(x)=$\int_0^{x^p}f(x)dx$ is concave.

I was able to show that F(x)= $\int_0^{x}f(x)dx$ is convex and obviously increasing, and that i might get somewhere by composing it with $x^p$

Comment: I somehow deleted half my title

Comment: How did you find F(x) is convex? Do we know the sign of f'(x) because I am getting F''(x) = f'(x) and for it to be a convex function we need F''(x) < 0. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.